# How to display tooltip in jquery ui theme style

Tags: jquery, user-interface, coding-style, themes, tooltip

Is there a jquery tooltip plug-in or a self-made solution where the tooltip appears in the style / colors of the jquery ui theme in use?

Perhaps by "abusing" the jquery ui dialog?

Comment: heh, ""abusing" the jquery ui dialog?". ahh that made me laugh. bit of a slow day today...

Comment: Dialog, you have been _very_ naughty today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [jQuery UI Tooltip](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Tooltip) in development... download it from [github](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/tooltip) and read through the comments on that page on how to use it.

Comment: Cool, exactly what I was looking for! I think I'll wait until it's released (hopefully soon!?) and then go for it.

Comment: Who knows when it'll be released, it's been in development for a while now :(

Comment: @werner5471 it is now in jqueryUI 1.9

Answer (score 1):

My company uses Qtip from Craigworks, and it already has the Themeroller support working.  It's the most bug-free tooltip system I've ever used:

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

If you get stuck on the Themeroller incorporation, there's very good help in the forum.